# How to remove the CA root certificate from a pfx file in Windows?

Tags: windows, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

On a windows 2012 R2 and a Windows 10 machine there is a pfx file which contains the certificate chain for the server.  I created this file using Windows MMC certificate export tool.  The choices were export all certificates in the chain if possible or only the one certificate.  The chain contains the root, two intermediary and then my server certificate.

I would like to remove the CA root certificate since the client should already have it, but leave the intermediary certificates.

How do you edit a pfx file to remove the one root certificate?

Comment: Split it with OpenSSL and then rebuild it with OpenSSL.  You could also import it at the client (assuming you're using a Windows command line) with `certutil -importPFX My <filename> NoRoot`.

Comment: OpenSSL worked.  Converted to a pem file, edited the pem file removing the root and converted back to pfx. Thank you.  Please post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with few lines of PowerShell code (no OpenSSL is required):

```
$path = "Put the path to a pfx file here"
$password = "Put password here"
$pfx = New-Object Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection
# import pfx to X509Certificate2 collection
$pfx.Import([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($path), $password, "Exportable")
# remove first root (self-signed) certificate
if ($pfx.Count -gt 1) {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $pfx.Count; $i++) {
        if ($pfx[$i].Issuer -eq $pfx[$i].Subject) {
            [void]$pfx.RemoveAt($i); break
        }
    }
}
# write back pfx to a file
$bytes = $pfx.Export("pfx", $password)
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($path, $bytes)
```

Comment: Good solution, however the root cert is in different places (3rd, 4th, etc...) in some pfx files (out of order) but modifying the code is easy.to handle it.  The openSSL solution to a pem file is nicer because you can also look at the certs and move them into their proper order manually.  Can probably be done in powershell as well but would take more coding.

Comment: Modified the code to handle root certificate at any place if presented. BTW, there is no "proper order" for pkcs#12 (and pkcs#7).

Comment: Re: Proper order: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56824/what-happens-when-intermediate-certificates-are-installed-in-the-wrong-order#56833

Comment: It is for SSL/TLS connection only. General pkcs#7/12 doesn't define the order. Other protocols may require different order.

Comment: This is why the openSSL solution is better, although yours is certainly very useful.  Moving them into the right order is enabled by editing the PEM file.  I"m sure powershell code could be written to move them based on the issuer and subject and that would be great. Doing it manually via the PEM enables you to move them individually although manually, while at the same time removing the root.

Comment: If you want to do this manually, then OpenSSL is a solution. Though based on your comments I suspect that you are trying to solve the problem that isn't a problem, because in the case of SSL, https library should handle the order by itself.

Comment: Run an SSLLabs.com scan of a server with the certs out of order and you'll see the out of order complaint.  An automated solution is best.  Would be a good powershell piece of code to specify tls and then have it reorder the certs according to specs and remove the root.  I will accept your answer though since the openssl isn't posted as an answer and your automated solution solves the problem in the original post.  Ordering them is a nice addon, if automated.

Comment: Can't tell for every web server, but least, IIS sorts certificates internally and sends them in required order.